# Cannot Create MVC Child

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm new to MVC, so please forgive my noobie question. I literally have a Person object/class and a Child object/class.

```
  public partial class Person
    {
        public Person()
        {
            this.Registrations = new HashSet<Registration>();
            this.Children = new HashSet<Child>();
        }

        public int PKey { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public int StateKey { get; set; }
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        public virtual State State { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Registration> Registrations { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }

 public partial class Child
    {
        public int PKey { get; set; }
        public int ParentKey { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    }
```

I have successfully created a view (Children.cshtml) which displays the person's children:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Children)
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-3"> @item.Name </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3"> @item.BirthDate.ToShortDateString()</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3"> @Html.ActionLink("Remove", "RemoveChild", new { id = @item.PKey, parentKey = Model.PKey })</div>
                </div>
            }

 @Html.ActionLink("Add Child to Registration", "AddChild", new { id = Model.PKey })
```

However, I'm stuck/confused on trying to create the AddChild view. I think I need to 'pass' the Parent key to the AddChild view, but I cannot get it to work. My AddChild view has @model NRMS.Models.Child at the top. My ActionResult in my controller looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AddChild([Bind(Include = "PKey,ParentKey,Name,BirthDate")] Child child)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Children.Add(child);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View();
}
```

I'm assuming I'm completely missing the boat somewhere. Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thanks.

BJ

Comment: `ActionLink` will point to a `[HttpGet] AddChild` method, and so there should be an `int id` parameter on that method.  However, you've only shown the [HttpPost] method.    There should be a `[HttpGet] AddChild` method.

Comment: Yes:        // GET: Children/Create
        public ActionResult Create(int? id)
        {
            return View();
        }

Comment: I'm not sure what to put in here to set the ParentKey

Answer (score 1):

The key pieces are first the name of the property here `new { id =`:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add Child to Registration", "AddChild", new { id = Model.PKey })
```

Which should match a parameter in your GET method, and which we can pass through the Child model:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddChild(int? id)
{       
    return View(new Child{ ParentKey = id });
}
```

By populated this property of the Child model, and passing it to `View(` it makes it available in the AddChild.cshtml view.  In your form there should probably be a hidden field declared inside the body of the form so that this value gets posted when saving:

```
Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.ParentKey);
```